# POST XML data with Groovy HTTPBuilder

Tags: xml, groovy, httpbuilder

I am trying to POST XML data to a URL using the HTTPBuilder class. At the moment I have:

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder('http://m4m:aghae7eihuph@m4m.fetchapp.com/api/orders/create')
http.request(POST, XML) {
body = {
        element1 {
            subelement 'value'
            subsubelement {
                key 'value2'
            }
        }
    }           

    response.success = { /* handle success*/ }
    response.failure = { resp, xml -> /* handle failure */ }
}
```

and upon inspection I see that the request does get made with the XML as the body. I have 3 issues with this though. The first is, it omits the classic xml line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

which has to go at the top of the body, and secondly also the content type is not set to:

```
application/xml
```

Then lastly, for some of the elements in the XML I need to set attributes, for example:

```
<element1 type="something">...</element1>
```

but I have no idea how to do this in the format above. Does anyone have an idea how? Or maybe an alternative way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. To add the XML declaration line insert [`mkp.xmlDeclaration()`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/xml/MarkupBuilderHelper.html#xmlDeclaration%28java.util.Map%29) at the beginning of your markup.
2. Passing [`ContentType.XML`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/apidocs/groovyx/net/http/ContentType.html#XML) as the second parameter to request sets the `Content-Type` header to `application/xml`.  I can't see why that isn't working for you, but you can try using a string of `application/xml` instead.
3. To set attributes on an element, use this syntax in the markup builder: `element1(type: 'something') { ... }`

Here's an example:

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.5.2')
import groovyx.net.http.*

new HTTPBuilder('http://localhost:8080/').request(Method.POST, ContentType.XML) {
    body = { 
        mkp.xmlDeclaration()
        element(attr: 'value') {
            foo { 
                bar()
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

The resulting HTTP request looks like this:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/xml, text/xml, application/xhtml+xml, application/atom+xml
Content-Length: 71
Content-Type: application/xml
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate

<?xml version='1.0'?>
<element attr='value'><foo><bar/></foo></element>
```

Comment: How do you print out your request?