# Posting XML with Groovy HttpBuilder

Tags: xml, groovy, httpbuilder

i am trying to post some xml data using Groovy's HttpBuilder.
[POST XML data with Groovy HTTPBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017126) answers the question on how to generate attributes (as id below)

```
<person id="1"></person>
```

but does not suggest how to specify value for this node.
i have tried with constructs such as

```
apicall{
  user "userName"
  person(name:"name") "personName"
}
```

which generates an XML

```
<apicall>
  <user>userName</user>
  <person name='name'></person>
</apicall>
```

but the personName is missing!
please suggest what am i missing here.

Answer (score 0):

See: http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/3017.
They use

```
body: {
  widget(id:'129033'){
    type("TFR")
  }
}
```

which will be encoded to

```
<widget id='129033'>
  <type>TFR</type>
</widget>
```

Comment: Thanks Will!
i was late by a moment :)
groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder helped me achieve this.

The required construct should be
 person(name:"name", "personName")
and that created the XML i wanted!

thanks for your reply though!